# Static Inner class returning null when instantiating

Tags: java, class, oop, private, inner-classes

I have a public class called Tournament which has a nested private static class called Team.

```
public class Tournament {

    private Team[] teams;
    private static int noOfTeams;
    private  Queue<Team> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    Team teamA,teamB,winner;


    public Tournament(int noOfTeams) 
    {
        this.noOfTeams = noOfTeams;     
        generateTeams();
    }


    private void generateTeams()    
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < noOfTeams; i++) 
        {       
            this.teams[i] = new Team();  // Returning Null here
            this.teams[i].setId(i);
            this.teams[i].setRank(i);       
            queue.add(this.teams[i]);
        }       

    }

}
```

So when I create an object of Tournament. The constructor calls the generateTeams() method.When I run this , it is returning a NullPointerException at the line:
 this.teams[i] = new Team();    (Which is highlighted in bold).

For some reason it is not instantiating the Team() object and hence assigning a null value to teams[i]

New to OOPS and nested classes. If possible explain in detail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'Static inner' is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate the array first

```
this.teams = new Team[noOfTeams];

for (int i = 0; i < noOfTeams; i++) 
{     
    this.teams[i] = new Team();   
    this.teams[i].setId(i);
    this.teams[i].setRank(i);       
    queue.add(this.teams[i]);
}
```

**But** as you are adding `Team` Objects to a queue, why do you even need an Array?

Comment: Still having the same issue , returns NullPointerException at this.teams[i]setId(i);

Comment: Did you do `this.teams = new Team[noOfTeams];` ?

Comment: Yes I did as mentioned . Issue still persists.
As mentioned , removed the array as I am adding in the queue anyway.
Works well...!
Thanks..!

Comment: *Yes I did as mentioned* - where did you mention it?  Why don't you edit your question with the code that you are using now.  Your comment `// Returning Null here` does not make sense - unless you are throwing an exception in `new Team` but how would I know, you are not sharing that code

Comment: Finally fixed it .
this.teams = new Team[noOfTeams];
and then in the loop did this 
teams[i] = new Team();

Works as expected now.
Thanks for the help..!

Comment: In your answer add in the loop this.teams[i] = new Team(); .
That should do.